# Difference among "suspicion" - "doubt" - "reservation"

Tags: meaning, word-choice, word-usage, nouns

I have a question related to word choice. I know the answer is "reservation", but I can't tell the difference among three other options. The question is as follows:

> If I were you, I would regard their offer with considerable ______ because it seems too good to be true.

A. suspicion
B. doubt
C. reservation
D. disbelief

I think that "suspicion" and " doubt" are both reasonable to fill in. Could anyone please explain?

Comment: Oxford Languages defines _reservation_ as _an expression of doubt qualifying overall approval of a plan or statement._ So, yes, _doubt_ would be a possible alternative. So would _suspicion_, although it implies a higher level of scepticism about the good faith of the people making the offer.

Comment: Are you sure this is copied accurately? I wouldn't use *reservation*, but **reservations**. I don't much like *doubt*, but *suspicion* and *disbelief* work well.

Comment: *...with considerable saltpinchiness*

Answer (score 2):

If this were me writing this phrase, I'd have said "considerable suspicion". I *have* reservations/doubts/suspicions (all three are fine), and for that reason, I regard the deal with *suspicion*.

I don't think it's technically wrong to say "regard it with reservation", but to me, that construction feels like something out of a Jane Austen novel -- something written in the early 1800s rather than 2020s. I've never heard the word used that way in modern speech.

In my experience, "reservations" is always plural when you're talking about having concerns; the singular form is only used as a noun, meaning a thing set aside for some specific use. I have a reservation for tomorrow night at my favorite restaurant, and I have reservations about whether they'll actually honor it.